# Https IIS is not working after deleting machinekeys folder

Tags: windows

I have deleted all my machinekeys folder in windows server 2013 which caused IIS ssl certification is not working anymore.
I tried to redeploy the certificate in IIS but https site binding is failing.
Does anyone have solution to recover IIS ssl functionality?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your only shot is restoring those keys or perhaps repairing Windows. Deleting the MachineKeys folder breaks Windows's ability to handle SSL connections. In the future, it's always best to rename a folder rather than delete it.